# JQuery animate performance optimization on Android tablets

Tags: javascript, android, query-optimization

Hi I'm trying to write an image slideshow. On the desktop works fine, on the ipad works fine, on the galaxy tab 10.1 is reeeeally slow. I've tried to use lower the image quality, reduce the numer of dom objects involved and some other things, but it doesn't seem to improve.

I also tryed to add a 0 degree z transormazion as some tutorial tells but it only make a worse render (some white horizontal lines appears).

What can i do to have a smooth scroll?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to thread your application. As in having a worker thread where all the loading is happening.

But it's not easy for us to give you pointers on how to optimize your code if you don't provide any code snippets.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not write it was a web page. No application :-(

Answer (score 0):

1) Like @Rasive answered -> consider using bg thread and preloading images

2) And on the webview showing your content set:

```
yourWebView.getSettings().enableSmoothTransition()
```

Comment: I'm sorry I did not write it was a web page. No application :-(